# How to get the json data from a php file on the server to the flutter app

Tags: php, json, http, flutter

I have a php file hosted on my college server and when i run this file on the server it works very well. I can get the json data after running my php file which is in the link http://www.alkadhum-col.edu.iq/Teachers%20Activities/get.php but when i was unable to got then when i had tried that in flutter on the app screen.

First, i tried to change the url doesn't work. Second, i tried to convert the json objects to .toString() and also doesn't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;
import 'dart:convert';

class Post {
  String name;
  String msg;
  String day;
  String date;

  Post({this.name, this.msg, this.day, this.date});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      name: json['name'].toString(),
      msg: json['msg'].toString(),
      day: json['day'].toString(),
      date: json['date'].toString(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomListView extends StatelessWidget {

  List teachers = [];

  CustomListView(this.teachers);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: teachers.length, 
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return createviewItem(teachers[index], context);
        },
      )
    );
  }

  Widget createviewItem(Post teachers, BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: new Card(
        child: new Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.lightBlue)),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            new Text(teachers.name),
            new Text(teachers.msg),
            new Text(teachers.day),
            new Text(teachers.date)
          ],),
        )
      )
    );
  }

}


Future<List<Post>> downloadJSON() async {
  final jsonEndpoint = "http://www.alkadhum-col.edu.iq/Teachers%20Activities/get.php";
  final response = await get(jsonEndpoint);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List teachers = json.decode(response.body);
    return teachers.map(
      (teacher) => new Post.fromJson(teacher)
    ).toList();
  }

  else {
    throw Exception("Unable to get JSON data");
  }
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
    theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
    ),
    home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter and PHP')),
    body: new Center(

    child: new FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
    future: downloadJSON(),

    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
    List<Post> teachers = snapshot.data;
    return new CustomListView(teachers);
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    }
    //return  a circular progress indicator.
    return new CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
    ),
    ),
    ),
    );
}
}
void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I got Format Exception: Unexpected character (at character 115) and some of data appers in a list not in a string form.

Comment: you can do it without data model

Comment: you are modelling your json data with the class that you've created which named Post

Comment: Yes but how to make it works

Comment: var data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
print(data['someData']);

Comment: I already did that. My problem is how to print them on my app screen?.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your data is not JSON data.

```
[
  {
    "name": "م.م علي ستار باراني",
    "msg": "امتحان مادة قواعد البيانات اول جابترين ",
    "day": "السبت",
    "date": "2019-06-20"
  }
][
  {
    "name": "م. امجد عباس التميمي",
    "msg": "امتحان مادة هندسة البرامجيات اول فصلين",
    "day": "الاحد",
    "date": "2019-06-21"
  },
  {
    "name": "م.م علي ستار باراني",
    "msg": "امتحان مادة قواعد البيانات اول جابترين ",
    "day": "السبت",
    "date": "2019-06-20"
  }
]
```

The problem is in these two brackets:

```
  }
][
  {
```

JSON code should be like this.

```
[
  {
    "name": "م.م علي ستار باراني",
    "msg": "امتحان مادة قواعد البيانات اول جابترين ",
    "day": "السبت",
    "date": "2019-06-20"
  },
  {
    "name": "م. امجد عباس التميمي",
    "msg": "امتحان مادة هندسة البرامجيات اول فصلين",
    "day": "الاحد",
    "date": "2019-06-21"
  },
  {
    "name": "م.م علي ستار باراني",
    "msg": "امتحان مادة قواعد البيانات اول جابترين ",
    "day": "السبت",
    "date": "2019-06-20"
  }
]
```